# I want to swap the position of two imageviews doing a slide animation

Tags: android, position, imageview, slide, swap

I am creating an android app in which I want to swap the respective positions of two imageviews doing a slide animation. I am unable to do this. It would help if I could get the code so that I can copy pate in my project.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html check this link

Comment: @Nirmal I want to swap the positions of two imageviews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing any of your code, it's hard to give you a more specific suggestion. An easy way to animate layout changes is to change the layout parameters of the images in code (on a button click or something). You would set the layout parameters of each ImageView to be the same as the opposite ImageView, and then use:

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

on the parent layout if you are in API level 11 or higher.

Otherwise, you could look into the [TranslateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html) and specify the coordinates of opposing images in your call.